# Mailflow error, on premise Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, mail-forwarding

So I am trying to create a mailflow rule to forward mail from user 1 to user 2 but keep running into this issue:

We'll say Bob Smith is user 1 and Tom Jones is user 2. Each has an email address on each of the two domains used by the company steelpies.com and ironpies.com (examples...), so we have:

Bob@steelpies.com

Bob@ironpies.com

Tom@steelpies.com

Tom@ironpies.com

Whenever I go to the mailflow rule to forward Bob@steelpies.com to Tom@steelpies.com it errors:

> There are multiple recipients matching the identity "Bob Smith".
>   Please specify a unique value.

Comment: use hub transport or just make a distro group

Answer (score 0):

You should create a transport rule with "recipient address matches pattern" parameter instead of "sent to" parameter, using the exact `bob@steelpies.com` address as pattern to seek. Then proceed as normal.